# Bokeh whisker head color

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, errorbar

I would like to plot error bars (std) for my points-line plot.
I didn't found the proper answer how to do this but one of the solutions is to use whisker.
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#whiskers

I worked for me pretty well but I have a problem how to change the head color of whisker head.

I used the **line color** property to change the color of line:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.Whisker

but It not changed the color of head (horizontal line). 
It remains black.
Is there a way how to do this?
or there is a better way how to plot error bars in color of line?

Example code from bokeh with red lines and black heads for errorbars:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Whisker
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

colors = ["red", "olive", "darkred", "goldenrod", "skyblue", "orange", "salmon"]

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, title="Years vs mpg with Quartile Ranges")

base, lower, upper = [], [], []

for i, year in enumerate(list(df.yr.unique())):
    year_mpgs = df[df['yr'] == year]['mpg']
    mpgs_mean = year_mpgs.mean()
    mpgs_std = year_mpgs.std()
    lower.append(mpgs_mean - mpgs_std)
    upper.append(mpgs_mean + mpgs_std)
    base.append(year)

source_error = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(base=base, lower=lower, upper=upper))

p.add_layout(
    Whisker(source=source_error, base="base", upper="upper", lower="lower", line_color='red')
)

for i, year in enumerate(list(df.yr.unique())):
    y = df[df['yr'] == year]['mpg']
    color = colors[i % len(colors)]
    p.circle(x=year, y=y, color=color)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 4):

The ends of the whiskers are configurable via the `upper_head` and `lower_head` properties, which are `ArrowHead` objects that have their own `line_color`, etc. The easiest way to configure them is probably like this:

```
w = Whisker(source=source_error, base="base", upper="upper", lower="lower", 
            line_color='red')
w.upper_head.line_color = 'red'
w.lower_head.line_color = 'red'
p.add_layout(w)
```

Though it's also be possible to pass an explicitly configured `TeeHead` to `Whisker` if you really want to do everything in one expression:

```
Whisker(..., 
        upper_head=TeeHead(line_color='red'), 
        lower_head=TeeHead(line_color='red'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: The second solution requires `from bokeh.models.arrow_heads import TeeHead ` and (at least for my example) resets the line_width to its default value which is about a factor two to large. The first one works like a charm.

Comment: Right, it was just meant to be illustrative of the technique, you would still need to to configure it fully to your needs.